# Need to iterate through a list of files and append text at the first line of the files in th list on a Linux CentOS system

Tags: php, sed

I need to be able to append the text `<?php`
to the beginning of php files in a list.

Comment: Are you asking for PHP code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry had to change the text it failed to print everything after the <?php line until I added some backticks to it.

Most of the research I studied online is done with sed or awk and a one example was in PERL. I am not focused so much on which language to use so long as I can get this problem solved. Would have been nice if Clam AV could have fixed this infection.

Comment: It'd also be nice if your question stated what OS . . . it sounds like the actual task you want to do is add a string of text at the beginning of several files, and you have a list of the filenames you want to modify.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. The topic has the OS, it is a CentOS Linux install.
Yes the text file has the folder location and the filename in a line by line format. 
I ran a cleanup script to clean eval base64 code from the files then it made a text file with the files that had been cleaned only problem was that it didn't put the `<?php` back at the top of the files it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You say 'append the text `<?php`', but I think you mean 'prepend'.

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but this should solve your problem:

```
for FileName in * ; do (echo "<?php" ; cat $FileName) > corrected_$FileName ;done
```

That will create a bunch of files with same names except prefixed with 'corrected_'.  If you want to alter files themselves then you could do this:

```
for FileName in * ; do (echo "<?php" ; cat $FileName) > /tmp/corrected ; mv -f /tmp/corrected $FileName ;done
```

...but be sure that's what you want.